# Is the feature [SHORTCUT-KEYS] 'Screenshot of an area to clipboard' missing in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

Tags: shortcut-keys, screenshot, 22.04

I noticed that the ability to 'Copy a screenshot an area to Clipboard (Shift+Ctrl+Print)' and previous screenshot functions [**SHORTCUT-KEYS**] are missing in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.  Is this an installation/user issue, or have they been deprecated?

**Clarification: I'm talking about the shortcut-keys, not the functionality itself.**

**22.04 LTS**
[image: 22.04 LTS]

**20.04 LTS**
[image: 20.04 LTS]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The feature is not missing. The shortcut to take a screenshot of an area now simply is <kbd>PrtScr</kbd>. After taking the screenshot, the result is available both in the clipboard and as a file.

Thus:

- Hit <kbd>PrtScr</kbd>
- Select the area with the mouse
- Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Paste the screenshot in your application. If there is a need, it is also available in `~/Pictures/Screenshots`.

The whole workflow of taking a screen shot was simplified. As soon as you take a screenshot, it will be both stored in a file under `~/Pictures/Screenshots` and be available on the clipboard. No need to think ahead: use make a shot and use the output, file or clipboard, that suits you at the moment.

Press <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> to have an interactive method, and remember just two key combinations for the quicker work: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd> for full screen and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd> for current window.

Comment: I'm looking for the shortcut to screenshot an area, not the fact that it's missing.

Comment: This is not answering the question. The feature discussed does not save a copy of the screenshot. It just puts it in the clipboard. Thus, no need to clean up that folder from time to time.

Comment: @SaTa The person asking the question clearly found this answered the question. The question was about the feature to copy a screenshot to the clipboard using a shortcut key. It is there, but it works differently than before, hence the 'Copy a screenshot an area to Clipboard ' shortcut is missing.

Comment: @vanadium, Thanks. I kind of agree. However, to me the question is about a specific "feature" as it is mentioned in the title. The feature takes snapshot of an area and pastes it into clipboard. The solution here does the same thing PLUS saving a copy. Personally, I use the original feature a lot. With this solution, I will end up with unwanted files in `~/Pictures/Screenshots`.

Comment: @SaTa yes, no everybody likes the change. It is always possible to reinstall gnome-screenshot and define the shortcut keys so it works as in previous versions. Alternatively, a cron job that deletes the files now and then can save you manual cleanup.

Comment: Yes, I ended up reinstalling gnome-screetshot and define a custom shortcut. The cron idea is interesting too...

Answer (score 1):

No, the feature is there as can be seen from the below graphic taken a few moments ago in `Screenshot`under Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (version 41.0)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround as I could not find the exact feature as in 20.04:

1. Install gnome-screenshot (It was not installed by default in Pop_OS! 22.04)

```bash
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install gnome-screenshot
```

2. Go to `Settings > Keyboard > View and Customize Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts`
3. Click on the `+` button to add a shortcut.
4. Add a name
5. Paste `gnome-screenshot -ca` as the command
6. Click `Set Shortcut`
7. Click the `Add` button

And give it a shot!

Answer (score 0):

The old functionality pro:

- one keyboard click Ctrl+shift+print
- directly saved into clipboard, no middle man or save actions(Enter, which does not work for me anyway)
- if i made a mistake: like making a screen shot of sensitive data - please don't discuss this point here - i just need to make another screenshot and the mistake gone. No file, no issue.

I know now, that my actions are saved in the Directory, and i have to delete from time to time.

Anybody, found a workaround to save the screenshot directly to clipboard without file saving?

Is my point a new question?
For me, the feature is missing!

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1247680)

Comment: Actually, not. this is not a new question.
I am also looking for a solution to get a screenshot directly into the clipboard like the original question. 

the suggested explanation do not answer the original question. its not the same like 20.04 version

Comment: Anyway it is not an answer.

Comment: I missed the feature too. We need to manually define a custom shortcut to bring it back. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1434547/889735).