# Screenshot selection in 22.04

Tags: 22.04, clipboard, screenshot, gnome-screenshot

I am trying to configure the 22.04 (Gnome 42) keyboard shortcut to get the "old" functionality of taking screenshots of area selections and pasting them into clipboard (<kbd>Ctrl + Shft + PrtScr</kbd> + select/release: done). The problem is that `$ gnome-screenshot -ac` doesn't copy the selection into clipboard unless there is an instance of gnome-screenshot utility running. Does anyone know how to work around this issue? *(I know it is possible to run the "new" interactive screenshot tool, but that takes too many clicks and is not what I want.)*

**Edit**: The issue has been fixed: `gnome-screenshot -ac` works as intended in Gnome 43.4 or perhaps even in the earlier versions.

Comment: Just use the print button `PrtScrn` see [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1404831/914580)

Comment: @Paul As mentioned in the question, this is not the functionality that I wanted, as it takes too many clicks to achieve the desired effect

Comment: @Iiro_Ullin It takes one click more than previously

Comment: @Paul Yes and that is already too much. Yet it becomes worse, if the "new" and the "old" selections overlap: then you must move the old selection before you can make the new selection. Anyways, my clicking preferences are not a matter of discussion here: the discussion is about how to fix/work around the clipboard bug in gnome-screenshot

Comment: @IiroUllin I ended adding `gnome-screenshot -i` to startup applications

Comment: I would like to change the location where the img is saved interactively. Is it possible ?

Comment: This feature was so useful. Unbelievable that it is no longer there out of the box.

Comment: For anyone wanting a solution and demo of the "new" interactive screenshot tool, here's mine: [Ubuntu 22.04: How to rapidly take a screenshot, save it as a JPG, and edit it using the Shutter program to add highlighting](https://askubuntu.com/a/1446364/327339)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `-c` command to copy the screenshot to the clipboard has a weird bug that doesn't copy the image when using `-a` to grab a selection.

A way to fix this is to make the command save the screenshot by adding `--file={/filepath/filename.png}` after the `-a -c`.

The command all together is `gnome-screenshot -a -c --file={/filepath/filename.png}`.

I don't know why this fixes the bug but it definitely works so you can try that.

*Hope this is what you wanted @Iiro Ullin. Good luck!*

Comment: Are you sure it's not copying the image? when I set the command to be `gnome-screenshot  -a -c --file=/home/betzalel-maor/Desktop/Screenshot001.png` I can paste the screenshot! In my answer I wrote `-c` before `-a`, so change it to `-a -c` and it should work. Hope that helped and good luck!

Comment: -c -a or -a -c or -ac etc, makes no difference -- it all does the same thing, however saving to a file does indeed fix the clipboard issue and can be used as a workaround. There's some clipboard bug that's been around for years and it seems to persist in this iteration of Gnome as well. I'll accept your answer if you reformulate it a bit to emphasize that that saving to a file somehow fixes the clipboard bug.

Comment: What do you mean, you want me to write another answer that will say just to save the screenshot and it should fix the bug?

Comment: The important piece in your answer is that saving the screenshot in a file with --file=... somehow fixes the clipboard issue. Everything else is either irrelevant or is already present in the question. If you edit your answer to get rid of all that filler, I'd be happy to accept it (or I can just type your fix into my original question and refer to your response).

Comment: Ok well I edited it, hope this is what you wanted :D

Comment: Sadly this solution didn't seem to reliably work for me, but it gave me an Idea of how to tackle the problem. I ended up saving the screenshot to a file and then manually adding it to the clipboard:  `sh -c "gnome-screenshot -a --file=screenshot.png; xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png -i screenshot.png"`

Comment: For me as well, just calling gnome-screenshot with `-a -c -f file.png` doesn't copy to clipboard, although using the UI and then "Copy to Clipboard" does. @A.P's approach works great.

Comment: @A.P Try specifying the full file name -- that worked for me...

Comment: I'm experiencing the same bug, but (I think) I can't use xclip as suggested by @A.P as I'm using Wayland. Fortunately, there's an xclip alternative for Wayland and it's in the official repos: `wl-clipboard`. So putting all together, for me what worked was: `sudo apt install wl-clipboard` and then the following command (which also removes the screenshot file in the end): `sh -c "gnome-screenshot -a --file=temp_screenshot.png; wl-copy < temp_screenshot.png; rm temp_screenshot.png"`.

Answer (score 43):

##### After installing Ubuntu 22.04

after you log out or restart the computer, the **old** `gnome-screenshot` is removed, so you need to reinstall it to make the old command to work.

```
sudo apt install gnome-screenshot
```

##### Add a Custom ShortCuts

Settings → keyboard → keyboard shortcuts → custom shortcuts

Custom shortcuts are at the end of list

```py
gnome-screenshot -c -a
```

I'm using `Shift + Ctlr + Delete` shortcut so that it doesn't interfere with the new **42** screenshot shortcuts."

[image]

###### In gnome 42 the default shortcuts for using the screenshots are:

1. `Shift+Print` takes a screenshot
2. `Print` take a screenshot interactively
3. `Alt+Print` take a screenshot of a window
4. `Shift+Ctrl+Alt+R` record a screencast interactively

When you press `ALT+PRINT` throws a message

> you can paste the image from the **clipboard**

To change keyboard shortcuts in GUI:

Settings -> keyboard -> keyboard shortcuts -> Screenshots.

Comment: Well, that was exactly my point: this doesn't work for me. When you press the shortcut key combo, it makes the sound and all that, but doesn't actually copy anything into clipboard (unless there is an instance of gnome-screenshot already running). Did you verify that it actually works, not just makes a sound?

Comment: Same issue. I followed you, but it doesn't make anything rather than just making a sound. Did it work for all the guys who upvoted? Your response would be a great help.

Comment: Same, using the custom command from the comment below worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/a/1458667/993724

Answer (score 19):

So this is what I did on my Ubuntu 22.04

Note this is for capturing an area onto the clipboard.

Install Gnome Screenshot: `sudo apt install gnome-screenshot`

Make sure that Xclip is installed. To install :

```
sudo apt install xclip
```

Create a custom keyboard shortcut. I used Ctrl + shift + Print Screen with the following command: `sh -c "gnome-screenshot -acf /tmp/test && cat /tmp/test | xclip -i -selection clipboard -target image/png"`.

Comment: This one worked for me. 
There is a dot inside the code block that is not part of the command

Comment: @tiriana I moved the period out of the code block.

Comment: I also did this :)

Comment: wow, this saved my workflow!

Comment: can you explain, why do we need sh -c "..." the whole command?

Comment: ubuntu 22, I use `copyq` to have a clipboard history. This method works, but sometimes the image get saved 2 times in history, sometimes only once. Anyway, it's a minor issue I can live with.

Comment: For some reason I started getting Permission denied on /tmp/test. I have no idea why. I changed it to `sh -c "gnome-screenshot -acf ~/screenshot && cat ~/screenshot | xclip -i -selection clipboard -target image/png"`

Answer (score 8):

You can select the part of the screen to screenshot by holding the <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> button.

This presents an option to select which should allow you to do a screen shot selection (which is what <kbd>Ctrl<kbd>+Shift</kbd>+PrtScr</kbd> used to do).

Comment: I know the poster wasn't looking for this answer - but it wasn't clear to me from their question that I could achieved this and I went down a rabbit hole until I discovered I could just hold down this key :)

Comment: It works, thanks!

Comment: please upvote this answer, this is the correct way, we just need to know it.

Answer (score 4):

Just press <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> then define your selection and press <kbd>Ctr+C</kbd> to Copy the Image to your Clipboard.

Answer (score 4):

Add this command as a custom shortcut

```
bash -c 'gnome-screenshot -a -c --file="$HOME/Pictures/screenshot.$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S).png"'
```

Such as shift+alt+print

Then you can press the shortcut and select areas, file is saved in the location with timestamp -- exactly the same behavior as old Ubuntu.

Comment: This worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

I get the concern about the new `PrtScr` tool requiring more clicks, but playing around with a bit I found two ways to get closer to the old user experience:

- if you use right-click to make the selection, you can click within an existing selection without problem.
- you can use `space` to take the picture