# How can I change "Print Scr" to capture all of the screen without asking question?

Tags: screenshot, gnome-screenshot

I moved to 22.04 last week. Up until this version, whenever I pressed "Print Scr" button it would capture the screenshot of the full desktop. Starting with 22.04 the "Print Scr"  button asks me whether I want to capture the full screen, partial screen, and few other options.

I want to go to the old behavior. If I press print screen button, I would like it to capture the whole screen without asking me any questions. I looked at the settings, I could not find anything related to that. Is there a way to go back to old behavior?

Being able to capture screenshots without the hassle is part of my job. This change really makes the life very inconvenient for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Screenshot selection in 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407422/screenshot-selection-in-22-04)

Comment: People will close your question, if they're not investigated. Check first, ask then ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You are free to change the assigned shortcut keys in "Settings", "Keyboard shortcuts", section "Screenshots" the way you prefer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked!

Comment: It will be good to place the check mark next to the question, i.e., "accept", to indicate this is the answer that helped you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pressing only <kbd>Print Scrn</kbd>, use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Print Scrn</kbd> for taking full page screenshots without the preference window, and use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Print Scrn</kbd> to take screenshots of a certain area.